# Load php files in parent files also stored data from form

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want to load a php code in a page called index (parent page). The problem occurs when you press the filter button because the page does not load correctly (it also loads the parent page) and it does not show me the selected data from the form that I will want to query in the database.

---

The index page have the code:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
          <div class="card">
              <div class="row mt-3">
                  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                      <select name="class" id="class_id" class="form-control select2" data-toggle = "select2" required>
                        <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select_a_class');?></option>
                        <?php
                        $classes = $this->db->get('classes')->result_array();
                        foreach($classes as $row):
                        ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"
                              <?php if ($class_id == $row['id']) echo 'selected';?>>
                                <?php echo $row['name'];?>
                            </option>
                        <?php
                        endforeach;
                        ?>
                      </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                      <select name="exam" id="exam_id" class="form-control select2" data-toggle = "select2"  required>
                        <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select_a_exam');?></option>
                        <?php
                        $exams = $this->db->get_where('exams' , array('session' => active_session()))->result_array();
                        foreach($exams as $row):
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"
                          <?php if ($exam_id == $row['id']) echo 'selected';?>>
                            <?php echo $row['name'];?>
                        </option>
                        <?php
                        endforeach;
                        ?>
                      </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                      <button class="btn btn-block btn-secondary" onclick="filter()" ><?php echo get_phrase('filter'); ?></button>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body tabulation_content">
                <div class="empty_box">
                      <img class="mb-3" width="150px" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/backend/images/empty_box.png'); ?>" />
                      <br>
                      <span class=""><?php echo get_phrase('no_data_found'); ?></span>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

---

The list page that i want to load

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <td ><?php echo $exam_id?></td>
          <td ><?php echo $class_id?></td>
        <td >333</td>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

---

The JavaScript filter

```
<script>
  $('document').ready(function(){
      initSelect2(['#class_id', '#exam_id']);
  });
  function filter(){
      var exam = $('#exam_id').val();
      var class_id = $('#class_id').val();
      if(class_id != "" && exam != "" ){
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '<?php echo route('tubulation/list/') ?>',
              data: {class_id : class_id, exam : exam},
              success: function(response){
                  $('.tabulation_content').html(response);
              }
          });
      }else{
          toastr.error('<?php echo get_phrase('please_select_in_all_fields !'); ?>');
      }
  }
  </script>
```

[You can see the result here on this picture]

[image: pic]

Comment: Can you point out, what the value of the action attribute of the form tag is? Also show us the JavaScript filter() method. What does this method?

Comment: Hy i add the JavaScript filter() method. I put <form> on top and is not working

Comment: stab in the dark, but shouldn't `tubulation/list/` be `tabulation/list/` (since you're using class `$('tabulation_content')`

Comment: I don't understand....could you can be more precise where I went wrong. Thank you